# How do you return more than one DataTable from a method?

Tags: asp.net, generics, list, datatable

I have class which has a method that needs to return three DataTables.  I thought I could use Generics but honestly I've never used them, so I'm trying figure it out.  It may not be the right thing here.

I have in my class Employee:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
{
  //calls to other methods in my class;
  //psuedocode
  GetDataTable1;
  GetDataTable2;
  GetDataTable3;

  return all three datatables;
}
```

On my presentation side I have three gridviews:

I create my class Employee and call GetEmployees and get back my list of DataTable, then

```
gridview1.datasource = datatable1;
gridview2.datasource = datatable2;
gridview3.datasource = datatable3;
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.  I have tried the class method definition above but I'm not getting it right.

Hoping for advice.  I do not wish to use three methods.  I am using C# and asp.net 2.0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add them all to a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and return that

Answer (score 5):

You can use a DataSet, which is designed to hold multiple DataTable objects and reference them by name.

Answer (score 3):

I would think it's the same way you'll return 3 variables from a method:

- return a collection
- create a structure to hold the 3 results
- use out parameters

Comment: Note that .Net already has a purpose-built collection or structure in the form of a dataset for items 1 or 2 on that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Return New DataTable() {Me.GetDataTable1, Me.GetDataTable2, Me.GetDataTable3}
```

yeah its vb *shrug*